# textallcaps="true" is not working in TextView [Android]

Tags: android, view, fonts, display

I have problem with textallcaps, in Android studio it showing fine, see image:

[image: AndroidStudioOK]

but when running on device text is still lowercase, see Image:

[image: DeviceNotOK]

Font is Fira GO,
I also tried different Uppercase fonts but getting still the same result.
any ideas How can I make it work?

Edit:
Font XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <font-family 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <font
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/firago_regular" />
  </font-family>
```

UI XML:

```
<TextView
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textColor="@color/maincolor"
            android:fontFamily="@font/firago"
            android:text="@{pagetitle}"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </TextView>
```

Comment: share your xml file

Comment: @PriyankaRajput ok, I edited question and added xlm code

Comment: You just added the font family xml, We need to check the UI xml

Comment: @PriyankaRajput my bad, now i added Textview, code

Comment: Check the value of pagetitle , what is you getting to set to the textview.

Comment: @PriyankaRajput "ფინბიურო"

Comment: I am sorry But I am unable to understand the text. I dont know this language.

Comment: @PriyankaRajput does text matter? its georgian language, this fira go font have uppercase support for georgian language as I know.  https://bboxtype.com/typefaces/FiraGO/#!layout=specimen

Comment: Is the device < API 14? Try ``app:textAllCaps`` instead, it was backported through appcompat. And the easiest way to check the font is to make add some capital letters to the text - if they display fine, you know it's a problem with the "all caps" code and not the font itself

Comment: Yes, if the text is already in small , then sometimes it wont effect textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here https://bboxtype.com/typefaces/FiraGO/ (on right side) is list of OpenType typographic features. One of these features is `case: case-sensitive forms`.
This can be enabled by applying `android:fontFeatureSettings="case"` attribute on the `TextView`.

*This is a bit tricky, but I think it will work*

[image]